# R - keep all columns but only select rows that meet multiple criteria from multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, select, dataframe, subset

I have many rows of eye-tracking data (longer fixations and shorter saccades) in my dataframe, each row corresponds to a sample taken by the eye-tracker (see column `timestamp`). The data proceeds progressively, with counts of fix and sac, their durations and whether each eye movement hits the targets (AOIs). Here’s a sample:

```
subj    timestamp   fix_indx    sac_indx    eventtype   dur AOI_1   AOI_2   AOI_3
MT  409 1   NA  Fix 83  NA  NA  NA
MT  426 1   NA  Fix 83  NA  NA  NA
MT  443 NA  1   Sac 17  NA  NA  NA
MT  459 NA  1   Sac 17  NA  NA  NA
MT  476 2   NA  Fix 100 0   NA  NA
MT  493 2   NA  Fix 100 0   NA  NA
MT  509 2   NA  Fix 100 0   NA  NA
MT  526 NA  2   Sac 10  NA  NA  NA
MT  543 NA  NA  Unclas  20  NA  NA  NA
MT  559 3   NA  Fix 233 1   NA  NA
MT  576 3   NA  Fix 233 1   NA  NA
MT  593 3   NA  Fix 233 1   NA  NA
MT  609 NA  3   Sac 11  1   NA  NA
MT  626 4   NA  Fix 240 NA  1   NA
MT  643 4   NA  Fix 240 NA  1   NA
MT  643 4   NA  Fix 240 NA  1   NA
MT  659 4   NA  Fix 240 NA  1   NA
MT  676 NA  4   Sac 13  NA  NA  0
MT  693 5   NA  Fix 250 NA  NA  1
MT  709 5   NA  Fix 250 NA  NA  1
MT  726 5   NA  Fix 250 NA  NA  1
MT  743 5   NA  Fix 250 NA  NA  1
MT  809 NA  5   Sac 9   NA  NA  0
MT  826 6   NA  Fix 256 NA  NA  0
MT  842 6   NA  Fix 256 NA  NA  0
MT  859 6   NA  Fix 256 NA  NA  0
```

I would like **to select only those parts of the dataset where in each AOI column the values are 0 (= outside target) and 1 (= inside target), i.e. eliminate the rows where any AOI column has `NA`** (all columns have mostly NAs with some 1s and 0s). I have 2 conditions to meet per AOI column. I have used the `subset` function:
`df1<-subset(df, 
+ AOI_1 ==0 | AOI_1 ==1 | 
+ AOI_2 ==0 | AOI_2 ==1)`

However, there are 118 different AOI columns in my dataset, so using `subset` would mean ending up with an extremely long code string.  Is there a way of doing this more neatly?

---

I run AntoniosK example but I get an error:
`mydfnew$uid <- 1:nrow(mydfnew)` # creates a user id colum (`uid`) 
`> mydfnew %>%
+ select(uid, starts_with("AOI")) %>%
+ filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
+ select(uid) %>%
+ inner_join(mydfnew, by="uid")`
`Error in select_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  object 'uid' not found`.

This is odd as the `uid` column was created correctly, as confirmed by `tail(mydfnew)` and `mydfnew$uid`... anyone knows what is going on here?

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you try it on your real dataset?

Comment: @Val the 1st error message is due to the "row.names" in the select command. Even my example doesn't work with that. Try to use another name like "row_index" because row.names is a R function and the select command gets confused and breaks. For the 2nd error I found it hard to believe it didn't work. Just take some time to clear your working directory and run everything from the beginning. This should work. uid is exactly the same as my id.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know which columns are the AOI-columns or whether there are columns in between it, it is better to create an index of the names of the AOI columns in combination with `complete.cases` as follows (in base R):

```
AOIcols <- names(df)[grepl("^AOI",names(df))]
df[complete.cases(df[,AOIcols]),]
```

Or with `na.omit` from the [development version of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) which has a `cols` argument:

```
library(data.table) #v1.9.5+
setDT(df)
na.omit(na.omit(df, names(dt)[grepl("^AOI",names(df))]))
```

In the data presented in the question, there are no rows for which the `complete.cases` statement is true. Applying the above code on the small dataset as given by @AntoniosK gives the same result:

```
  id subj AOI_1 AOI_2
1  1    A     0     1
2  2    A     0     0
```

An alternative `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% semi_join(df, by="id")
```

---

From what I understand is that the dataset contains eye-tracking data. As such datasets can be quite big, lets try the different methods on a somewhat bigger dataset that mimics the dataset in the question:

```
# load the need packages
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# create a datatable
DT <- data.table(id=seq_len(1e5),
                 subj=rep(LETTERS[1:10],each=1e4),
                 dur=rnorm(1e5, mean=70, sd=10),
                 event=sample(c("fix","sac"), 1e5, TRUE, c(3,1)),
                 matrix(sample(c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,NA), 1e7, TRUE, prob=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,1)), ncol=100))

names(DT) <- gsub("V","AOI_",names(DT))

# create an identical dataframe
DF <- copy(DT)
setDF(DF)

# the benchmarks
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(replications = 10, order = "elapsed", columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          jaap = na.omit(DT, names(DT)[grepl("^AOI",names(DT))]),
          nico = DF[complete.cases(DF[,5:ncol(DF)]),],
          ant1 = DF %>% select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% select(id) %>% inner_join(DF, by="id"),
          ant2 = {DF %>% select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% select(id) -> IDs
            DF[IDs$id,]
          })

  test elapsed relative
1 jaap   0.467    1.000
4 ant2   1.093    2.340
3 ant1   1.191    2.550
2 nico   1.430    3.062
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the AOI columns are at the end, you can select them using something like:

```
my.data[,7:ncol(my.data)]
```

Now you can use `complete.cases` to select those that don't have NAs.

```
complete.cases(my.data[,7:ncol(my.data)])
```

Comment: the AOI columns are not at the end of the dataframe, they are sort of in the middle, i.e. there are other columns to the left and to the right of my 118 AOI columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "AOI" colums can have only 0, 1, NA as values you can try something like the following (simple) example. The only thing you need to do (in advance) is to create an id for your rows and have it as a column:

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(id = 1:5,
                subj = "A",
                AOI_1 = c(0,0,1,NA,NA),
                AOI_2 = c(1,0,NA,0,1))

dt

#   id subj AOI_1 AOI_2
# 1  1    A     0     1
# 2  2    A     0     0
# 3  3    A     1    NA
# 4  4    A    NA     0
# 5  5    A    NA     1


dt %>% 
  select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>%  # keep only id and columns that start with "AOI"
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%       # keep only rows that don't have NAs
  select(id) %>%                      # select the ids of those rows
  inner_join(dt, by="id")             # join back info for those rows only

#   id subj AOI_1 AOI_2
# 1  1    A     0     1
# 2  2    A     0     0
```

Run the example step by step to see how it works and then do any modifications needed. You can create the row id within the process if you prefer.

The inner join at the end is not really needed, as you can just simply spot the rows without NAs in the AOI columns and just select those, instead of joining back. It will be faster if you have to deal with millions of rows:

```
dt %>% 
  select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  select(id) -> IDs

dt[IDs$id,]
```

@Jaap the benchmarks seem to change (a bit) every time I run them.
I'll post some examples based on your dataset:

A)

```
> # the benchmarks
>  system.time(na.omit(dt, names(dt)[grepl("^AOI",names(dt))]))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> 
>  system.time(df[complete.cases(df[,3:ncol(df)]),])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02 
>  
>  system.time(df %>% select(id, subj, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% semi_join(df, by="id"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02 
> 
>  system.time(df %>% select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% select(id) %>% inner_join(df, by="id"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01
```

B)

```
    >  system.time(na.omit(dt, names(dt)[grepl("^AOI",names(dt))]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> 
>  system.time(df[complete.cases(df[,3:ncol(df)]),])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01 
>  
>  system.time(df %>% select(id, subj, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% semi_join(df, by="id"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01 
> 
>  system.time(df %>% select(id, starts_with("AOI")) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% select(id) %>% inner_join(df, by="id"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.04
```

Comment: Yes that's correct, each AOI column can only have 0,1, NA as values and all AOI columns have a mix of all three values, so there are no columns without NAs.

Comment: This doesn't work on larger dataset. See my answer. Could update your solution so that it works on the dataset I created as wel?

Comment: I think for the first error the select command gets confused when you use row.names as the name of a column. Make sure that it exists and try to rename it before you run the select. For the second one I have to check when I have more time.

Comment: @AntoniosK see my answer for the correct approach with dplyr

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into it. Your approach is correct. But mine is wrong only if we assume that the ids start from the begging for each subject. In my process the id is simply a row id and just counts rows. Doesn't depend on the subject column. If it did then your approach is the only correct one as it uses the proper row identifier which is the pair id, subject.

Comment: @AntoniosK it indeed gives the right results now, but stil is slower than both my `dplyr` and my `data.table` approach

Comment: Definitely slower than the data.table approach as my approach includes a join. Is it really needed? Maybe not. As the aim is to spot the row ids that don't have NAs at the AOI columns and then pick those rows from initial dataset. Will try to update my method excluding the join. Still interesting to see why it didn't work for @Val.....

Comment: @AntoniosK I've updated my answer with a dataset that mimics the situation of OP better and with a better benchmark